# Docker Image not running. Error Command failed with exit code 127

Tags: node.js, docker, flowise

The GitHub repo is: https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise

The project already has a `Dockerfile`. I've ran the following to create a Docker image for the project:

```bash
docker build --no-cache -t zulele/flowise:1.1.0 .
```

The image was created successfully. But when I ran a container from the built image:

```bash
docker run -d --name flowise -p 3000:3000 zulele/flowise:1.1.0
```

I got the following error:

[image]

I thought maybe the error is regarding Docker not being able to locate the run file. So I copied the packages folder separately in the image by adding the following command in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY packages ./packages
```

But I still got the same error. Then, I located the run file in the Docker container files and added the path to that file in the package.json file. But then it gave me the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have working directory set to `/usr/src/packages` and you're copying files to `packages/server`. However, *package.json* scripts looks for the file in the `package/server/bin` directory. So `packages` is put twice in the path. The solution is to change working directory to `/usr/src`, or remove `packages/` from all `COPY` instructions.

Comment: I have changed the working directory to `/usr/src`
I got the same error:
`2023-09-10 23:53:16 yarn run v1.22.19
2023-09-10 23:53:16 $ run-script-os
2023-09-10 23:53:17 $ cd packages/server/bin && ./run start
2023-09-10 23:53:17 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2023-09-10 23:53:17 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
': No such file or directory't execute 'node
2023-09-10 23:53:17 error Command failed with exit code 127.
2023-09-10 23:53:17 error Command failed with exit code 127.`

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue with today's commit 032cf6bbda57ab2aade5053d67a51c9f86721805 . I used your exact commands and the container is now running.
What is your version, what does `git log -1` print?

But, what are you after? Are you trying to run a community version of flowise in docker or do you want to test a modification?
There are 2 Dockerfiles in the repo. You tried the one in the root folder, have a try with the one in directory `docker`.

Go into directory `docker` and follow the instructions from `README.md`.

Here is my simplified version of `docker/Dockerfile` that also references a specific version, as opposed to `latest`:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

USER root

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip
RUN npm install -g flowise@1.3.4

WORKDIR /data

CMD "flowise"
```